# React: TypeError: this._modal.$el.on is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, babeljs

So I'm new to react and I'm trying to use a boilerplate but I'm getting the following error in the chrome console. Sorry if this is a repeat question but I've tried to google it and found nothing. Thanks for the help in advance.

*(Console)*

```
TypeError: this._modal.$el.on is not a function
```

*(index.js)*

```
import React from 'react'
import UIkit from 'uikit'

export default class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._modal = UIkit.modal(this.refs.modal, {
      container: false,
      center: true
      // stack: true
    })

    console.log(this._modal)

    this._modal.$el.on('hide', () => {
      this.props.onHide()
    })


    this._modal._callReady()

    if(this.props.visible) {
      this._modal.show()
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { visible } = nextProps
    if(this.props.visible !== visible) {
      if(visible) {
        this._modal.show()
      } else {
        this._modal.hide()
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref="modal">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to handle your modal with your compoenent state and refs are usually used for DOM manipulation. 
What you can do is to initialize your state:

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
    this.state= {
      isOpen : false
  }
 }
```

in your `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
const { visible } = nextProps
if(this.props.visible !== visible) {
  this.setState({
   isOpen: visible
  })
}
```

}

and in your render method:

```
render() {
return (
  <div ref="modal">
    {this.state.isOpen && this.props.children}
  </div>
)
}
```

Let me know if this issue still persists. Happy to help

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input. When I do that it gives me errors. I logged the `this` variable and it says on the console that this.state is set to null

Comment: have you initialized the state in constructor ?